# LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0, Update phrase list feature makes phrase list global

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0, Update phrase list feature makes phrase list global, even when it was set to local in preview.luis.ai. The API specification doesn't contain any info about global/local phrase lists flags. How to keep phrase list local?

Comment: The phrase list can apply to the entire app with the Global setting, or to a specific model (intent or entity). If you create the phrase list, as a descriptor from an intent or entity, the toggle is set to not global. If you create a phrase list (created globally by default), then later apply it as a descriptor (feature) to a specific model, it is removed from the other models.